# Secure .Net Core 3 Web API with AAD Token

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

Due to some technical constraints, we are doing Username/Password AAD authentication when user login.

Users will input their username and password into our custom login page and our application calls [IPublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication).

I'm planning to use the returned token to call another Web API application(also connecting to the same AAD). In the Web API application, I did the following:

1. Added the following code in startup `services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme).AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));`
2. include the following settings in my appsettings.json file
   `"AzureAd": {
   "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
   "ClientId": "<Application ID>",
   "TenantId": "<Tenant ID>"
   }`
3. Secure my web api using [Authorize]

I then use Postman to construct a call to the Web API based on the returned token. I included `Authorization: Bearer <JWT Token>`. The Web API returns

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

My questions are

1. Can Web API application validate the username/password acquired token?
2. If the token can be validated in Web API application, how can I do it since I'm getting the above error?

Comment: Can u kindly check if the application has any roles assigned in the AAD?

Answer (score 2):

I test in my site and it work well, you could refer to the following steps:

1.Register Webapi app in azure ad.

2.Click `Expose an API` and `Add a scope` e.g. `webread`.

[image]

3.Click `Manifest`, change `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` to `2.0`.

[image]

4.In visual studio webapi `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme).AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, 
options =>
{
    options.Authority += "/v2.0";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new[]
    {
        options.Audience,
        $"api://{options.Audience}"
    };
});
```

5.Register client app in azure ad.

6.Click `Authentication`, set `Default client type` as `Yes`.
[image]

7.Click `Api Permission`>`Add a permission`, select `My APIs` and choose the webapi your registered before.

[image]

8.In visual studio client app, set scope with webread:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://1890e822-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/webread" };
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

From the document you provided you are using MSAL to get access token using Resource Owner Flow in Azure AD V2.0 endpoint .

From [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#code-initialization) , when validating access token which issued from Azure AD V2.0 , you should add `/v2.0` to Authority :

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    // This is a Microsoft identity platform web API.
    options.Authority += "/v2.0";

    // The web API accepts as audiences both the Client ID (options.Audience) and api://{ClientID}.
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new []
    {
    options.Audience,
    $"api://{options.Audience}"
    };

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the setting, and now I'm getting another error "Bearer Error: Invalid Token".. But each time I make the call, I will re-generate the access token but still get the error.

Comment: @WenHao , what is the detail error message of your new error ?

Comment: Initial the error message is Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
After making the change, the error message is Bearer error="invalid_token". Is there anyway I can see the full error? I'm planning to go through the entire tutorial to see the difference between my setup and the tutorial setup (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API)

Comment: Use fiddler to trace the response to find the inner error message .